# How can I reduce data in a significantly smaller size without losing it's "Representational" significance?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, curve-fitting, graphical-model, reduced-form

So here I am trying to make sense of some test results from temperature chamber for testing electronics. [Temperature vs Time Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAR7g.png) shows the final output of the test. The data recorded by temperature sensor in the chamber over time. *The column Time is actually the value of time elapsed since 00:00 AM but in minutes.*

**The data is in reality made up of around 5000 data points. The resulting file size is in range of 3-5 MBs which makes it difficult to utilize on our analyzing tool. The analyzing tool does a check some of the following points**:

1. Did Test start correctly?
2. Did the Test parameters change as per definition at specific time windows?
3. At what points in time did the monitoring parameters show undesirable errors (sudden swings or fluctuations from desired value range)

**I would like to compress these data points by some factors( 25-50%) without losing the representational information (the peaks, troughs and fluctuations). What methods could I use for this purpose?**

The test begins like this :

| time | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 158.53 | 34.8 |
| 158.56 | 34.2 |
| 158.60 | 33.5 |
| 158.63 | 32.9 |
| 158.67 | 31.9 |
| 158.70 | 31.3 |

it goes on until first checkpoint of ~ -39°C where it stays at same temperature for next 50 mins.
there after temperature will start increasing until it 60° like this

| time | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 208.53 | -39 |
| 209.56 | -38 |
| 212.60 | -34 |
| 218.63 | -30 |
| 228.67 | -20 |
| 242.70 | -5 |

and so on until it reaches 60

| time | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 3xx.yy | 58 |
| 3xx.yy | 59 |
| 3xx.yy | 60 |

and so on.

For similar tests having square wave or rectangle wave, I have been thinking of using arithmetic means over a sample of 250 points to get a reduction of factor 20. But I am not sure how to proceed when there is a curve or saw tooth wave. I'd be glad if someone could push me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell us what your "analyzing tool" does and what the result of an "analysis" might be.  What is "representational information" and how do you quantify it?  How large is a "bit large"--that is, how much compression do you need? It would help to post a simplified but realistic dataset in a form that is computer-readable, because it is difficult to perform much of an analyses by just glancing at pages of numbers.